Fantasy movie about a doctor
I watched this movie in 2003 on TV, so it was probably released between 1999-2003. This movie was kind of a fantasy movie.
Details I remember:
As far I remember, this movie includes a married couple who are doctors. His wife leaves for a place to help people living there, but she dies in an accident on the way. She was pregnant at that time. Later, he starts visiting his wife's patients. One day, a patient tells him that he (patient) came to deliver message from doctor's wife. Doctor goes to his home and starts searching for some kind of a cross symbol. He also takes help of a nun.
Some weird things happen at his house. Later, he visits to a place where his wife died. Her soul asks him to visit a place where he finds his newborn daughter and brings her daughter back.
That's all details I remember.
Other Details:
His wife had a some kind of symbol like a cross across her shoulder.
I googled around and found What Dreams May Come, but it is not. Any idea about the movie. Thanks.

This is the plot of Dragonfly from 2002 with Kevin Costner.

Joe and Emily Darrow are doctors in a Chicago hospital. Seven months pregnant Emily travels to Venezuela to help natives in the Amazon area. She dies when a bus is hit by a landslide and plunges into the river below. Her body is never found by the local authorities. Without taking time to grieve Joe returns to work. One night he is awakened by his wife's dragonfly paper weight that falls and rolls across the room. His wife always had a passion for dragonflies and even had a birthmark on her shoulder which resembled a dragonfly.

The rest of the plot unfolds as you described. Later remade as Saaya in India. Here's the trailer:




Thanks @walt. You're a life saver. I didn't watch the Hindi version though it was on air a few months ago.

I have seen both version but I remember Indian one more.
